# Will this hold self inside a block?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

OK, this code on ARC holds self inside the block:

```
dispatch_async(someQ, ^{
    [self doSomething];
});
```

and that can be solved by

```
__weak MyRequest *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(someQ, ^{
    [weakSelf doSomething];
});
```

but what if doSomething has a lot of references to self? Because doSomething code will run inside the block isn't the same of all code of doSomething is on the block directly?

Do I need to pass weakSelf to doSomething so the method can use weakself references instead of self? Something like

```
__weak MyRequest *weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(someQ, ^{
    [weakSelf doSomethingUsingThisSelf:weakself];
});
```

Comment: `doSomething` is already called on the weak reference.

Comment: yes, I know but inside doSomething there are a bunch of references to self...

Comment: So what's the question? What do you need to know about `self` inside the `doSomething` method?

Comment: if those selfs will hold references to self, not deallocating.

Comment: It all depends on the code in `doSomething` which you haven't provided.

Comment: You don't need to use weak reference in `dispatch_async`, temporary retain cycles are ok.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a circular reference, so you don’t need a weakself at all. The block is holding a reference to self, but self isn’t holding a reference to the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing:

```
MyRequest *__weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(someQ, ^{
    [weakSelf doSomething];
});
```

...when there are no more references to `self`, `weakSelf` automatically becomes `nil`.  So the async callback will end up sending `doSomething` to `nil` in the even the object is destroyed before the callback, which will do nothing.

If `weakSelf` is not nil, it's just a pointer to an object.  When you send a selector to an object, there two implicit arguments: `self` and `_cmd` (see the [documentation for IMP](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tag/IMP)), section 6.1).  So `weakSelf` becomes the implicit `self` in those calls.  At that point, `self` is a strong reference, so the object won't get destroyed out from underneath you during the `doSomething` call chain, but referencing `self` from `doSomething` doesn't cause a reference count to increment because the block doesn't know anything about what goes on inside of `doSomething`.

Comment: Even worse can happen, if `dispatch_async` block had multiple references to weak self then half of them might be send to object and other half to nil. Welcome to async world :-)

Comment: Well, you will at least get a warning from xcode if you access a weak reference multiple times in the same scope.

Comment: Seriously it does that now? I know examples when weak ref would survive thru scope guaranteed by external factors. I just can't believe Xcode can make that deep analysis.